# Redo rsync to preserve hard links?

Tags: rsync

I'm copying a Raspbian partition from one SD Card to a stand alone Raspbian install on a new SD Card. Based on a suggestion elsewhere, I ran:

```
rsync -av --exclude=/mnt / /mnt
```

but now I'm concerned that I didn't preserve hard links because I didn't include the -H directive and instead rsync made copies of files instead of preserving hard links.

How can I correct this possible error? Can I run some form of rsync to fix this? such as:

```
rsync -avH --delete-after --exclude=/mnt / /mnt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your idea is right.

Here is a test:

```
/foo$ stat -c '%i-%n' *
658846-egg
656129-spam
656129-test


/bar$ rsync -av /foo/ .
sending incremental file list
./
egg
spam
test
sent 229 bytes  received 76 bytes  610.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00


/bar$ stat -c '%i-%n' *
657110-egg
663431-spam
663560-test


/bar$ rsync -Hav --delete-delay /foo/ .
sending incremental file list
test => spam

sent 107 bytes  received 19 bytes  252.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00


/bar$ stat -c '%i-%n' *
657110-egg
663431-spam
663431-test
```

On a different note, its better to use `--delete-after` rather than other similar options i.e. `--delete-before`, `--delete-delay`, `--delete-during` because these options decide which files to delete either before or during the transfer.

Comment: In case this is not clear, heemayl is looking at the [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) numbers to detect hardlinks -- hardlinked files will have the same, unique number.   This is similar to what I mentioned to you elsewhere about doing a test with `ls -l` to see the link count.

Comment: "On a different note, its better to use --delete-after rather than other similar options..." so just like my originally posted suggestion?

Comment: @BartmanEH yes..right..

Comment: @BartmanEH Glad i could help :)